# Orientation twisted on the $2$-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-geometry, orientation

If one is asked to verify that the canonical orientation on the $2$-sphere $S^2$ is twisted by the antipodal map, is it right to say that this is so simply because the Jacobian matrix of the map $A\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by

$$(x,y,z)\mapsto (-x,-y,-z)$$

has determinant $-1$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks. I bother you with another (silly?) question. If one is besides asked to calculate the pull-back through the antipodal map of the volume form that induces the canonical orientation on the $2$-sphere, is it right to think of that canonical form as the $3$-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\omega=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$, so that the pull-back will result in $-\omega$ ?

Comment: No! The restriction of a 3-form to the 2-sphere is automatically zero. The canonical volume form on the sphere is the restriction of $xdy \wedge dz + y dz \wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Actually the OP's argument is not sufficient, because it would also imply that the antipodal map reverses orientation of the $xy$-plane, which is false. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's not that simple. Consider a similar example: Let $M$ be the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb R^3$ -- that is, $M$ is the set of all points of the form $(x,y,0)$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.  Even though the antipodal map of $\mathbb R^3$ has Jacobian determinant $-1$ as you noted, and it takes $M$ to itself, in turns out that its restriction to $M$ is actually orientation-preserving.

The thing about $S^2$ that's different is that the antipodal map also takes the outward unit normal $N$ of $S^2$ to itself.  The area form $\omega$ of $S^2$ is given by 
$$
\omega = i_N (dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)|_{TS^2},
$$
where $i_N$ represents interior multiplication by $N$. It follows that 
\begin{align*}
(A|_{S^2})^*\omega 
&= i_{A^{-1}_*N} A^*(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)|_{TS^2}\\
&= i_N ( -dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)|_{TS^2}\\
&= -\omega.
\end{align*}

(The reason this calculation doesn't apply to the $xy$-plane is that $A$ reverses the direction of its normal.)

Comment: Thank you Professor Lee. I'm trying to solve the problem using a "local" technique. It'd be wonderful to know your opinion about it. I provide the (hopefully good) solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, is it right to write down the antipodal map in local coordinates as

$$(\theta,\phi)\mapsto(\pi-\theta,\phi+\pi)$$

so that

$$ dA_{(\theta,\phi)}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

and its determinant is everywhere negative so that the orientation is twisted?

Comment: This almost does it. The only gap is that spherical coordinates do not cover the whole sphere, so this only proves that the antipodal map is orientation-reversing on the domain of spherical coordinates. However, it's easy to fill in the rest of the argument: Since the antipodal map is a global diffeomorphism of the sphere, it is either orientation-reversing everywhere or orientation-preserving everywhere, and your calculation rules out the latter. (Or you could use that fact that the domain of spherical coordinates is dense, so the determinant must be positive everywhere by continuity.)